# Add an image to count down script

Tags: javascript, image

I want to add an image next to "Click here to Download"
Meaning when count down is over it should look something like this:
**Click here to Download** and this image should be beside it **http://svastara.info/.s/img/icon/download1.png**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<!--
var count = 30;
var obj;
window.onload = function () {
  obj = document.getElementById('delayed');
  obj.onclick = function () {
    if (count <= 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      if (count == 30) {
        waitForIt();
        return false;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}

function waitForIt() {
  obj.firstChild.data = 'Link will be available after ' + count + 'secs';
  if (count <= 0) {
    clearTimeout(cd);
    obj.firstChild.data = 'Click here to Download';
    obj.className = 'go';
    return;
  }
  count--;
  cd = setTimeout('waitForIt()', 1000);
}
//-->
</script>
```

---

```
<div>
<a id="delayed" class="stop" href="http://www.epiclosers.com/">Download (30sec)</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, how do I disable so that it won't start count down automatically, but only when users clicks it the count down starts?

Comment: Okay, how do I disable so that it won't start count down automatically, but only when users clicks on it the count down starts?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, why not include that image as hidden where you want it:

```
<img id="downloadImg" src="http://svastara.info/.s/img/icon/download1.png" style="display:none"/>
```

and reveal it when the timer completes, by setting the `display` style property to `block` or `inline`:

```
function waitForIt() {
    obj.firstChild.data='Link will be available after '+count+'secs';
    if(count<=0) {
        clearTimeout(cd);
        obj.firstChild.data='Click here to Download';
        obj.className='go';
        document.getElementById("downloadImg").style.display = "block";
        return;
    }
    count--;
    cd=setTimeout('waitForIt()',1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var CountdownTimer = function( id, count, imgurl ) { this.construct(id, count, imgurl); }
CountdownTimer.prototype = {
    construct: function(id,count,imgurl) {
        this.id = id;
        this.object = document.getElementById(id);
        this.count = count;
        this.interval = null;
        this.counted = false;
        this.img = new Image(); // preload
        this.img.src =  imgurl;
        this.img.border = "0";

        (function(obj) {
            obj.object.onclick = function() {
                return obj.onclick();
            };
        })(this);
    },

    tick: function() {
        this.count--;
        this.render();

        if(this.count == 0){ 
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            this.interval = null;
            this.object.appendChild(this.img);
        }
    },

    onclick: function() {
        if(!this.counted) {
            this.counted = true;
            this.render();
            (function(obj) {
                obj.interval = setInterval(function() {
                    obj.tick();
                },1000);
            })(this);
            return false;
        } else if(this.count == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    },

    render: function() {
        if(this.count > 0)
            this.object.innerHTML = "Download (" + this.count + " second" + (this.count == 1 ? "" : "s") + ")";
        else
            this.object.innerHTML = "Download Now";
    }

};

window.onload = function() {
    var c = new CountdownTimer("delayed",3,"http://svastara.info/.s/img/icon/download1.png");
};
```

Comment: It would be better if you would plug those in since i know so little about javascript.

Comment: Okay, how do I disable so that it won't start count down automatically, but only when users clicks it the count down starts?